Battery performance at high altitudes
I want to install large Li-ion battery containers along with Power Conversion Systems (PCS)  of 50 MWh scale at an altitude of ~4000m. But my battery/PCS manufacturer has specified altitudes of <2000 for ideal functioning, else it would get degraded faster. So to meet the load delivery by the user as per schedule, I have two options before me:

Size up the system according to the temperature-performance graph
Place the whole systems under temperature, pressure and humidity regulators to simulate normal working environment for the batteries.

Kindly suggest what is advisable. If any battery energy storage systems deployed at such high altitudes, kindly let know. Thank you in advance.

I don't think we can give you much advice: the manufacturers' engineers know what the specific issues are, but we don't. On a much smaller scale, I've had an alkaline battery in a scientific instrument rupture from internal pressure in the stratosphere. That was a surprise.

Isn't there a third option: replace the cells more often? Technology might advance before the first replacement anyway, such that the replacement cells work well at an altitude of 4000 m.

@AndrewMorton good option, but from a practical business standpoint, I cant rely on positive speculation, have to take decisions based on current knowledge

At an altitude of ~4000 meters, placing the whole system under temperature, pressure, and humidity regulators is advisable.

This sounds like something you would either have to ask the manufacturer or qualify and test yourself

The atmospheric pressure difference between 2000m and 4000m is 0.2 bar (20kPa). Keeping the batteries at the elevated pressure is of course possible but rather expensive. There are several engineering issues to solve:

Have an enclosure system rated for 20kPa differential pressure.
Are the battery packs provided by the manufacturer in secondary enclosures that can be pressurized?

Is the enclosure system hermetic or does it need active pressure control?

Are the enclosures pack-scale or bank-scale?
Do you want a big container with batteries in it that you walk into through an air lock?

Is the air pressure a concern for thermal management only? If so, increased air flow would solve the heat removal.


Those are early questions you may want to think about.
Then there's the cost vs benefit ratio: what is  the operational cost to running the batteries at 20kPa below the rated atmospheric pressure? Will there be a net benefit to running them 20kPa above ambient?
